# Make oauth1 request with Axios node

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, axios

Can you make an oauth1 requests using axios? I can't seem to find any examples. Thinking my problem is dynamically creating the `oauth_signature` and `oauth_nonce`. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks!